# UPSERT SALES FORCE OBJECT WITH AZURE DATA FACTORY

Tags: polymorphism, salesforce, azure-data-factory

When I upsert a object with a polymorphic foreign key, the following error is returned:

"type must be specified for polymorphic foreign key field"

How do i specify the type? I have a polymorphic relationship with Account and Contact.

Comment: Hi @Leandro, could you plz visit https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Br0QAAS and let me know if it's helpful?

Comment: In Azure Data Factory, lookup activity is used to execute any query on salesforce table. Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce